# Uploading an image selected by the user into the database with Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, image-uploading

Please bear with me since I only learned to code a few months ago. I am having trouble uploading images selected by the user into a database. I am able to upload hard-coded images (e.g. "C:\imageName.jpg").

My jsp code:

```
<form:input path="pic" type="file" class="btn" name="image" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
```

EDIT

Thank you M. Deinum, after reading the link you posted, I have added this bean:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>

</bean>
```

My controller now has this code:

RequestMapping now contains this: `headers = "content-type=multipart/*"`
Additional parameter: `MultipartHttpServletRequest request`

```
@RequestParam(value="image", defaultValue="") MultipartFile file

byte[] bytes = null;
if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                bytes = file.getBytes();
                InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
                inputStream.read(bytes);
                inputStream.close();
            }
```

My new error code:

```
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
```

FURTHER EDIT

For anyone interested this is the entire code of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/processsettings", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "content-type=multipart/*")
public String processSettings(@ModelAttribute("changeUser") User changeUser, BindingResult result, HttpSession session, Model model, HttpServletResponse response, MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
@RequestParam(value="image", defaultValue="") MultipartFile file) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

    byte[] bytes = null;

    if (!file.isEmpty()){
        bytes = file.getBytes();
        InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
        inputStream.read(bytes);
        inputStream.close();
    }
    changeUser.setPic(bytes);
    userService.updateUser(changeUser);
    session.setAttribute("currentUser", changeUser);

    return "Settings";
}
```

Comment: Read [the manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart) I would say?

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear. The file could not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of other beginners like me, this is how we solved it. My original code was actually more correct.

RequestParam should be:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/processsettings", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSettings(@ModelAttribute("changeUser") User changeUser, BindingResult result, HttpSession session, Model model, HttpServletResponse response,     
@RequestParam(value="pic", defaultValue="") CommonsMultipartFile pic
```

Code was as simple as:

```
if (!pic.isEmpty()) {
    byte[] imageByte = pic.getBytes();
    changeUser.setPic(imageByte);
}
```

Important jar to include:

commons-io-2.4.jar